# No 'Div Container' button in CKEditor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I've got CKEditor 4.5.0 working on a Drupal 7.42 install. I'm now trying to find a way to wrap more than one HTML element inside a DIV (I want an image and caption to be wrapped in a single DIV).

On the *CKEditor Profile* I got 'Div container' selected under *Buttons and Plugins*. As I understand it this should give me a 'Div container' button in the Wysiwyg, which then opens a dialogue. But it ain't there.

All the buttons I've selected are in the toolbar. It's just that selecting 'Div container' doesn't appear to be doing anything.

I've tried manually installing the [Div Container Manager](http://ckeditor.com/addon/div) but this also doesn't seem to have any effect. (And it shouldn't, because the plugin comes with the 'standard' CKEditor package).

Please tell me I'm missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, I solved this by replacing the standard library with the full library. Seems odd as Div container is part of the standard library but it works.

When replacing the library, make sure to clear both Drupal's and your browser's cache.

Comment: Nothing odd about it. Most people don't know what a Div is.

Comment: @No Sssweat - True, but not what I called weird. What I find odd is that you need to install the full library to get a feature that's part of the standard library.